# Is it possible to automate the creation of an .edmx file?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ado.net

Say, for example, you have a connection string to a database that is already set up.  I realize that you can "create model from database", but I am wondering if there is a way to skip this step by triggering it automatically.

I would like to integrate this into a larger code generation program that creates Visual Studio solutions which is why I am wondering if this part can be automated.

The end goal is to have a user fill out a form with general project information (including their connection string) and then generate the solution which would include an .edmx based on the connection string provided (assuming there is an initialized MS SQL db on the other end).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underlying utility is called [EdmGen2](https://github.com/cincuranet/EdmGen2). You can call it from command line.

Also there are number of third party tools that can do it, some of them has command line interface.

Also there is LightSwitch technology that already doing it.